# Why "Contact Encounter" (ContactEncounter) object is not available in my org?

Tags: standard-objects, work.com

I want to create a custom field on "Contact Encounter" (ContactEncounter) object related to Work.com. But the object is not available in my org. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ph_api.meta/ph_api/erm_resource_contact_encounter_business_api.htm) of Contact Encounter,

> This API must be used only for person account-enabled orgs.

Therefore, can you check if [personAccounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328922&type=1&mode=1) is enabled for your Org? If not, you need to have them enabled and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had already enabled and setup person Accounts but that did not help. Contact Encounter is the Health Cloud object and it got available as soon as Health Cloud licenses are enabled in my org. Thanks.